# How to add PDF file created with BytesIO into a FileField in a model of Django

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab, bytesio

I can create a PDF file using reportlab in a Django application. However, I can't add it into a FileField in a model. I wonder how to transfer an io.BytesIO data into FileField in Django.

This is summary of my views.py.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfbase.cidfonts import UnicodeCIDFont
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics

buffer = io.BytesIO()
cc = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=A4)

# describe something
font_name = "HeiseiKakuGo-W5"
cc.registerFont(UnicodeCIDFont(font_name))
cc.setFont(font_name, 7)
cc.drawString(65*mm, 11*mm, 'test')

cc.showPage()
cc.save()
buffer.seek(0)

exampleObject= get_object_or_404(SomeModel, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
exampleObject.exampleFileField.save('test.pdf', File(buffer)) # here! this sentence doesn't work.
exampleObject.save()

return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='test.pdf')
```

The point is the sentence below doesn't work. I think "File(buffer)" is not appropliate.

```
exampleObject.exampleFileField.save('test.pdf', File(buffer))
```

Although once I tried to save a pdf into a FileField after creating a pdf file in a directory as a temporaly file, I prefer to do it by using io.BytesIO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your missing `buffer.get_value()`

I also use `ContentFile` instead of `File` though not sure it's necessary.

I just tested the following snippet and it works using reportlab==3.5.32

```
import io

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

from my_app.models import MyModel

buffer = io.BytesIO()
canv = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=A4)
canv.drawString(100, 400, "test")
canv.save()
pdf = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()

my_object = MyModel.objects.latest("id")
my_object.file_field.save("test.pdf", ContentFile(pdf))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That works very well. This is my first post on stack overflow. From your post, I also learned how to summarise my code in order to post a question here.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to `seek(0)` on your `buffer`, since it's been used previously, I wouldn't be surprised the buffer would be at the end and result in an empty file saved in Django.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!!
Sorry, I made a wrong summary. In my actual application, "buffer.seek(0)" is described. My application can create a pdf file. However, It can't save a pdf file into a FileField.